# sqlalchemy flask ignoring an and_ and func.DATE in filter query

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have this query that is trying to find a record given the same day and a status:

```
ld=LunchDay.query.filter(and_(func.DATE(LunchDay.timestamp == datetime.date.today()), LunchDay.status==1))
```

The model:

```
class LunchDay(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'lunch_day'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    user = relationship("User", foreign_keys=[user_id])
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, index=True, default=datetime.today())
    status = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

It runs and doesn't throw an error, yet it seems to not regard date.  It will find entries with dates like yesterdays in the DateTimeField of the database:

```
2018-11-13 00:00:00.000000
```

Which is yesterdays date, but it is picking it up based just on the status almost just like it is looking at it as an OR.  The imports I use are:

```
from sqlalchemy import func, and_
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print out the actual sql that is being generated by your query to see what is happening. E.g.:

```
ld=LunchDay.query.filter(and_(func.DATE(LunchDay.timestamp == datetime.date.today()), LunchDay.status==1))
print(ld)
```

Prints:

```
SELECT lunch_day.id AS lunch_day_id, lunch_day.timestamp AS lunch_day_timestamp, lunch_day.status AS lunch_day_status
FROM lunch_day
WHERE DATE(lunch_day.timestamp = %(timestamp_1)s) AND lunch_day.status = %(status_1)s
```

There you can see that the equality of `lunch_day.timestamp` and the param `timestamp_1` is being passed to the `DATE` function.

Which is actually pretty easy to see in your sqlalchemy query: `func.DATE(LunchDay.timestamp == datetime.date.today())`. I assume you want to convert `LunchDay.timestamp` to a date and *then* compare it to `datetime.date.today()` which should be `db.func.DATE(LunchDay.timestamp) == date.today()`.

```
print(LunchDay.query.filter(and_(func.DATE(LunchDay.timestamp) == datetime.date.today(), LunchDay.status == 1)))
```

prints:

```
SELECT lunch_day.id AS lunch_day_id, lunch_day.timestamp AS lunch_day_timestamp, lunch_day.status AS lunch_day_status
FROM lunch_day
WHERE DATE(lunch_day.timestamp) = %(DATE_1)s AND lunch_day.status = %(status_1)s
```

One other thing to note is that multiple statements passed to `filter()` are automatically treated as an `and_()`, so you can simplify your query a little by removing that:

```
LunchDay.query.filter(func.DATE(LunchDay.timestamp) == datetime.date.today(), LunchDay.status == 1)
```

Comment: This did it, my parenthesis was just in the wrong spot and thanks for the extra info too! awesome!